# German phrase for “Someone has to get laid.”

Tags: idiom, phrase-request, slang, insult

If someone is participating, e.g., in a passive-aggressive, disproportionate, stuck-up, or micro-management behaviour because he didn’t get to copulate for some time, a typical expression to make that person even more irate is to say:

> Someone has to get laid.

I am however having difficulties translating this expression, which provides an explanation for the inappropriate behaviour and at the same time mocks that individual. I can’t think of either a female, male, or unisex expression.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to your English version:

> Da muss ([wohl](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wohl_vermutlich_doch)) jemand flachgelegt werden.

Variations:

> Jemand muss mal wieder flachgelegt werden.
>   Jemand muss wohl wieder flachgelegt werden.
>   Da muss jemand mal wieder flachgelegt werden.
>   Da muss wohl jemand mal wieder flachgelegt werden.

"Someone didn't [have sex] in a long time":

> Da hat wohl jemand schon lang nicht mehr.

Although it's not necessarily an insult. Also as a question:

> Ist schon lang her (seitdem du das letzte Mal ran durftest), was? *(rather towards males)*
>   Sag, wann hast denn du das letzte Mal?

Don't know if these are too general:

> Da muss/sollte jemand mal wieder.
>   Jemand muss/sollte mal wieder.

Comment: Thank, these expressions are however quite bloated (word count and letters), and not as neat as the English one. I've only heard the second one with "gevögelt" behind it.

Comment: @FranzKafka That's the problem with English-to-German translations most of the time. :(

Comment: "Gevögelt" is quite rude and also very explicit. Since the context should be clear, you do not need to add it here.

Answer (score 5):

In Swiss German (call it a dialect, we call it the proper German) we tend to say:

> Öpper hets mal wider nötig

which freely translated to standard German would be written:

> Jemand hat es mal wieder (dringend) nötig
> OR
> Jemand hat es (dringend) nötig

Variations would also be:

> Hier hat's jemand (dringend) nötig
>
> Der/Die braucht's mal wieder (dringend)

Comment: I'd tend to use "Da" instead of "Hier": "Da hat's aber jemand dringend nötig". Wouldn't you use "Da" in Swiss German at all (in this context) or is it just a preference using "Hier"?

Comment: Actually I tried to apply *school learned German* for the answers. Just added Swiss German at the beginning for an origin of my answer :) - That said, in Swiss German it depends heavily on the region. While where I come from you'd say `Da häts glaubs epper (gröbers) nötig`, in Bern/Biel someone'd rather say `Hie hets öpper mau ume nötig`

Comment: The phrase "es nötig haben" is common not only in Switzerland. It nags me that I didn't think of it.

Comment: @Grantwalzer well, it's no competition ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since you also (in a comment) asked for short versions, the shortest I've actually heard is the expression:

> Er/Sie ist wohl untervögelt.

or obvious albeit slightly longer variations:

> Da ist wohl jemand untervögelt.

Comment: This is not so "discrete" as the others. Some things should not be named direcly...